# Converting automatically between Celsius, Fahrenheit & Kelvin on change event of each textbox value?

Tags: java, temperature

I need some help in writing a simple Java GUI program (for self-learning and exercising) that converts temperature units between Celsius, Fahrenheit & Kelvin.

IMAGE:
[image]

The Request: whenever I write a digit value in any textbox (i.e. 123 in Celsius), I want the value to get converted automatically in all other text boxes without using a button.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author mohammedh
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jClear = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jExit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jC = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jF = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jK = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Temperature Converter");

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Celsius");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Fahrenheit");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Kelvin");

        jClear.setText("Clear");
        jClear.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jClearActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jExit.setText("Exit");
        jExit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jExitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jC.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jCActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jF.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jFActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jK.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jKActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(89, 89, 89)
                        .addComponent(jClear)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jExit))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jK)
                            .addComponent(jC))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jC, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jF, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jK, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jClear)
                    .addComponent(jExit))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jCActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        
        
    }                                  

    private void jExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        System.exit(0);
    }                                     

    private void jKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    private void jClearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        jC.setText(null);
        jK.setText(null);
        jF.setText(null);
    }                                      

    private void jFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        
    }                                  

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public javax.swing.JTextField jC;
    public javax.swing.JButton jClear;
    public javax.swing.JButton jExit;
    public javax.swing.JTextField jF;
    public javax.swing.JTextField jK;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Edit the question: add the tag corresponding to the language you are using (Java?) and add code formatting so that the question can be read by humans. Then also tell what exactly you need help with, what result did you expect and what did you get instead?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a [keylistener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? what results are you getting?

Comment: Hi Lundin, noted, thanks. Scratte, I think that's what I need. Sebastian, I haven't tried any action for that purpose, all I did so far is adding actions of 'exit' and 'clear', now I need to know how to implement the keylistener. thanks all!

Comment: Scratte, I think what I need is more like an Event Listener. If I input a digit in the Celsius box, I want the digit to get converted automatically in the other boxes, without a convert button.